logto.io | get a jwt token on login to access my api
I'm using logto.io to manage my app authentication with React.
When I only authenticate using the frontend, everything is fine as described on the docs.
Let's say this is my AuthProvider component, wrapping LogtoProvider:
const config: LogtoConfig = {
    endpoint: AUTH_ENDPOINT,
    appId: AUTH_APP_ID,
};

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
    return <LogtoProvider config={config}>{children}</LogtoProvider>;
};

With that config, the authentication flow works:

guest is identified as guest.
"login" navigates to the logto login page.
the callback component retrieve the query params and identifies the user as expected.

The problem: The token retrieved is not a JWT that can be used to identify at the backend.
Now, I added resources and scopes:
const config: LogtoConfig = {
    endpoint: AUTH_ENDPOINT,
    appId: AUTH_APP_ID,
    resources: [API_URL],
    scopes: ['account', 'profile'],
};

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
    return <LogtoProvider config={config}>{children}</LogtoProvider>;
};

After that change - I got an error before navigate to the login page:

"invalid_target"


"resource indicator is missing, or unknown"

I tried to put any combination for the resources list:

the logto core app URL
the backend URL
the frontend URL.
all of the above, none of the above, part of the above.
used app ids instead of URLs.
with / without scopes.

What do you think can be the problem?

To retrieve a valid JWT for the backend, I had to:

In Logto Admin Console - go to Authorization -> API Resources.
Create API Resource.
enter API Identifier.
Add Permission scope.

In your frontend Provider, now configure the missing parts:
const config: LogtoConfig = {
  endpoint: AUTH_ENDPOINT,
  appId: AUTH_APP_ID,
  resources: [API_URL],   // <--- the API Identifier you mentioned in admin console
  scopes: [SCOPE], // <-- the scope you added in admin console
};

Now, When you'll need to get an access token for that specific API:
function MyComponent() {
  const { getAccessToken, isAuthenticated } = useLogto();
  const [token, setToken] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
        getAccessToken(API_URL).then(setToken)
    }
}, [isAuthenticated])

}


